# How to control the nodes in the active node group in blender python？

Tags: python, node-editor, add-on, properties

I'm working on a plugin that controls the output value of a node with a specific name in the active node group via an option in the N panel, as shown in the image below. but now it is not automatically synchronized, I think when I select a node group it should automatically synchronize in advance according to the value of the node should be checked, but I currently do not know how to modify this code, can anyone give help?

[image]

```
class WorldNodeSearchPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
"""Creates a Panel in the Sidebar of the Node Editor"""
bl_label = "Search World Environment Nodes"
bl_idname = "NODE_PT_search_world_nodes"
bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
bl_region_type = 'UI'
bl_category = "Search"

@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):        # 
    active_node = context.space_data.node_tree.nodes.active
    return context.space_data.tree_type == 'ShaderNodeTree' and \
           context.space_data.node_tree == bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree and \
           active_node is not None

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
   
    active_node = context.space_data.node_tree.nodes.active
    if active_node.type == 'GROUP':            
        group_node_tree = active_node.node_tree           
        camera_nodes = [node for node in group_node_tree.nodes if node.name == 'Node 1']
        if len(camera_nodes) > 0 : 
            camera_node = camera_nodes[0]
            layout = self.layout
            world = context.scene.world
            col = layout.column()
            col.prop(world, "camera_bool", text="Node 1")


def update_camera_value(self, context):
world = context.scene.world
active_node = context.space_data.node_tree.nodes.active
if active_node.type == 'GROUP':
    group_node_tree = active_node.node_tree
    camera_nodes = [node for node in group_node_tree.nodes if node.name == 'Node 1']
    if len(camera_nodes) > 0:
        camera_node = camera_nodes[0]
        camera_node.outputs[0].default_value = 1 if self.camera_bool else 0
                  

class HDRLightSettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
bpy.types.World.camera_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
    name="My Boolean",
    description="Node 1",
    default=False,
    update=update_camera_value
)
```